How to add dynamic metadata on [slug] page in next.js app router
The documentation wasn't much help, so I came here. I am trying to add metadata for my blog posts but I cannot figure out how to do that. This is my articles/[slug]/page.tsx code shortened:


'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import fetchBlogPosts from '../../../../pages/api/get_content';
import ArticleHeader from '@/app/components/articleHeader';
import { firestore } from '../../../../firestore';
import { collection, addDoc, query, where, getDocs, Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
const ReactQuill = dynamic(() => import('react-quill'), { ssr: false });


type BlogPost = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  image?: string | null;
  content: string;
  slug: string;
  tags: Array<{ name: string }>;
};

const ArticlePage = ({ params, }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
 
};

export default ArticlePage;



What do I need to do to have dynamic metadata?

You can use generateMetadata. In my example, I set dynamic metadata for my video detail page:


export const generateMetadata = async ({
    params,
    searchParams
}: {
    params: { id: string };
    searchParams: { id: string };
}) => {
    const video: Video = await getVideo(params.id);
    return {
        title: video.title,
        description: video.description,
        keywords: video.tag
    };
};

export default async function Detail(props: any) {
      return <div>Video detail page</div>
}



